# Short Java-script code that will not run, even after debugging

Tags: javascript

I've been working on this assignment, converting pseudocode to java-script.

I feel confident I have it correctly, but when I try to execute it, I only get a blank white screen.

I put it through the sandbox and managed to correct most of the syntax errors that could keep it from running, but it still refuses to work or display anything.

I'm still learning and I don't know what I would do without the sandbox to help debug my code, but I'm stuck at what to do when it doesn't find anything further.

Any suggestions to debug java-script code for a complete newbie?

This is the code:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">

// Declare variables
var username;           // potential username entered by user
var char1;              // one character extracted from username
var anyDigits = False;  // variable to signify presence of digits
var index;              // loop variable for extracting characters
var BR = "<br />";
var ES = "";

// Display program heading and requirements and ask for username
document.write("This program helps you set up a valid username." + BR);
document.write("Your username must be at least 8 characters long," + BR);
document.write("   start with a letter, and contain at least 1 digit." + BR);
username = prompt("Please enter your name: ", ES);

// Check for length of username
while (username.length < 8) {
    document.write("ERROR...your username must be at least 8 characters long." + BR);
    username = prompt("Please enter your new username: ", ES);
}

// Check that first character is a letter
// Substring function has three arguments: string, starting position, and ending position
char1 = username.substr(0, 0);
while (char1 !== isLetter()) {
    document.write("ERROR: the first character of your username must be a letter." + BR);
    username = prompt("Please enter your new username: ", ES);
}

// Check that there's at least one digit in the username
while (anyDigits !== True) {
    // Check each character, set anyDigits to true if a digit
    for (index = 1; index < username.substr(index, index); index++) {
        char1 = username.substr(index, index);
        if (isNumeric(char1)) {
            anyDigits = True;
        }
    }

// If anyDigits is still false, no digits were present
    if (anyDigits !== True) {
        document.write("ERROR:...your username must include at least 1 digit." + BR);
        username = prompt("Please enter your new username: ", ES);
    }
}

// Thank the user and end the program
document.write("Thank you! Your new username is: " + username);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `isLetter` function?

Comment: What sandbox? What do you mean by "debugging", have you actually run it using a debugger to see where it starts doing something unexpected?

Comment: You can't use `document.write()` and `prompt()` like that in a browser; the user won't be able to see the `document.write()` output when he's looking at the dialog. In general browsers will show the graphical all the DOM changes (including adding text) when you script has finished executing. The right way to do interaction is to create elements (e.g. `<input>` and `<button>` elements) which the user can interact with, and put event handlers on them. Also, in general avoid `alert()` and `prompt()` because if you have a bug and cause an infinite loop it will be very hard to escape.

Comment: isLetter returns True if all characters in the string are letters of the alphabet. Sandbox is a place you can copy your code and it will run/analyze it (danml.com/sandbox/). Regarding the document.write() and prompt, I'm just following the directions from the book. It has been working for other code I have practiced with, but not this one. Thanks for your replies! Mike

Answer (score 2):

true and false are case-sensitive.

Change True to true 
and False to false

You can use a debugger too like firebug (addon for firefox) or for chrome simply press F12 key for the debugger. You would definitely get an error in the console for cases such as above.

there are no such functions called isNumeric() or isLetter() in javascript. You could try this

```
if(isNaN(parseInt(char1))) 
{
    //it is a string  
}
else
{
    //it is a number
}
```

Comment: I changed them to lower case, and now it executes and presents me with a prompt box, but it's locking up after I enter anything.  There is a message on the browser tab:"ERROR the isLetter() is not defined."  Not sure if I'm using it in the wrong syntax form or something else.

Comment: Using the Firebug confirmed the isLetter as not defined. I altered the line for isLetter() as follow, with no success: while (!(isLetter(char1))) {

Comment: also just realized the isNumeric() function I'm using is also reported as not defined.  Are these two commands/functions not included in Java-script? The book makes it sound like they are.

Comment: Thanks for the updated suggestion! I seem to be having other underlying issues with this code.  For one, the char1 = username.substr(0,0) does not result in the first letter of the username typed.  I have it setup now to display the char1 value during execution for testing, but it always comes back as blank, like it's not reading the username value or the syntax is incorrect. The substring syntax is basic, string.substr(start,length) and that is what I have, though 'string' is substituted for 'username'. What exactly am I doing wrong at this point?

Comment: I figured out the issue with the substr(), I needed to changed the last argument, 0 to a 1.